# Importing Python Modules

Tags: python, django

I'm asking this because I couldn't find any precise answer for my problem. I need to import a python script from another location into my current location.
Here's the directory structure :

C:\Users\dhi\workspace\BasicRegression\Create&&Bkp-Inputs\create&&bkp.py **<-- Needs to Import**
C:\Users\dhiw\workspace\basics\Login.py **<-- Needs to be Imported by create&&bkp.py**

What line should be included in "create&&bkp.py" to Import "Login.py" ?
basics,Create&&Bkp-Inputs are Folders.

Comment: You are asking for trouble by using `&&` in your file names...

Comment: why ? any way to escape it in case its some sort of a special character ?

Comment: Don't use such characters, it's horrible and can lead to unexpected side effects on different systems and configurations.

Comment: Thanks for you advice @septi. I have changed the name "Create_And_Backup.py"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python looks for modules along the `PYTHONPATH`, which you can append to relatively easily.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\dhiw\\workspace\\basics\\")

import Login
```